# Plotting functions by factor in R

Tags: r, plot, plyr

I'd like to call plots from a dataframe by factor(s), such that for each factor (or combination of factors) a separate plot is formed, containing all relevant rows.

I can call regular plots in this way using a combination of `matplot` and the `plyr` package. However, I now need to plot functions, whose coefficients are called from a dataframe.

A simplified working example contains two factors and three coefficients. The actual dataset is large and the number of rows per factor varies.

```
df <- data.frame(fac_1 = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'),
             fac_2 = c('X', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'X', 'Z', 'Y'), 
             param_1 = c(1, 2, 5, 3, 6, 1, 6),
             param_2 = c(3, 6, 6, 4, 5, 3, 4),
             param_3 = c(7, 8, 2, 6, 2, 6, 1))
```

An example function (note this is specific to row 1)

```
curve_func <- function(x, y = 1) {
    df$param_1[y] +
    df$param_2[y] * x +
    df$param_3[y] * x^2
}
```

Calling a single `curve` plot

```
curve(expr = curve_func,
      from = 0,
      to = 5,
      type = "l")
```

I'm afraid I am struggling to see where to go from here. I understand that the `add = T` parameter can be used to overlay multiple `curves`, but I can't yet see how I can make use of that in this instance.

Finally, I realise that I could 'manually' plot each curve (i.e. apply the function to each row by inputting a fine sequence of *x*-values, then matplot *y* vs. *x*), but am hoping for a nicer alternative?

Thanks very much for any help or guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### base plot

If you want to stay with base plot, this

```
curve_fct <- function(p1, p2, p3) {
  continue <- FALSE
  for (i in seq_along(p1)) {
    curve(p1[i] + p2[i] * x + p3[i] * x^2,
          from = 0,
          to = 5,
          type = "l",
          add = continue)
    continue = TRUE
  }
}

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, curve_fct(param_1, param_2, param_3), keyby = .(fac_1, fac_2)]
```

will create a plot for each combination of `fac_1` and `fac_2` with as many curves as parameter sets for each combination.

### EDIT: baseplot with annotation

You can also show the factors in the title of the plot:

```
curve_fct2 <- function(txt, p1, p2, p3) {
  continue <- FALSE
  for (i in seq_along(p1)) {
    curve(p1[i] + p2[i] * x + p3[i] * x^2,
           from = 0,
           to = 5,
           type = "l",
           add = continue)
    continue = TRUE
  }
  title(main = txt)
  return(length(p1))
}
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, curve_fct2(sprintf("Factors: %s, %s", fac_1, fac_2), 
                       param_1, param_2, param_3), 
          keyby = .(fac_1, fac_2)]
```

### `ggplot2`

In a similar way, you can create a number of graphs using `ggplot2`. Please note the usage of package `polynom` which is an additional improvement.

```
library(polynom)
library(ggplot2)

curve_fct_gg <- function(p1, p2, p3) {
  gg <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 5)), aes(x))
  for (i in seq_along(p1)) {
    # define polynomial function to be plotted
    p <- as.function(polynomial(c(p1[i], p2[i], p3[i])))
    gg <- gg + stat_function(fun = p)
  }
  print(gg)
  return(length(p1)) # to avoid empty data.table
}
setDT(df)[, curve_fct_gg(param_1, param_2, param_3), keyby = .(fac_1, fac_2)]
```

Comment: Thanks @Uwe for a creative solution that does just what I was hoping for. Ticked this as the answer because it remains in base plot.

Comment: May I also ask -- is there a way to label each plot with its corresponding factors (paste into 'text' or 'main', for example)? Can 'fac_1' and 'fac_2' be unlisted and pasted in this case?

Comment: I've added a title which prints a text passed to the plot function. I prefer `sprintf` over `paste` to create the text from the factors because I find it easier to code and read.

Answer (score 0):

I can provide a ggplot2 answer, not sure if you wanted to stay within the packages you've mentioned, though.

This sounds like a good situation for the facets feature in ggplot2. I would try:

```
ggplot(dataframe, aes(x = x_var, y = y_var)) + 
  geom_smooth() +
  facet_grid(. ~ factor1)
```

You can also use facet_wrap to arrange the factor graphs differently.

See more here: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_(ggplot2)/

Comment: Perhaps, an interesting approach but doesn't work with OP example. I believe the question is how to plot multiple curves with parameters given in `df` for each factor combination but not the parameters itself.

Answer (score 0):

Different approach picking up Mustafa's idea to use `ggplot2` with faceting.

This requires to precompute y-values of all curves before plotting:

```
library(data.table)
library(polynom)
np <- 10 # number of points to plot curves
x <- seq(from = 0, to = 5, length.out = np)
plot_data <- setDT(df)[
  , param_set := seq_len(.N), keyby = .(fac_1, fac_2)][
    , .(x, y = as.function(polynomial(c(param_1, param_2, param_3)))(x)),
    keyby = .(fac_1, fac_2, param_set)]
```

Plotting is done with

```
library(ggplot2)
gg <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = x, y = y, group = param_set, colour = factor(param_set))) +
  geom_line() 
gg + facet_grid(fac_1 ~ fac_2)
```

which creates:

[image]

or more compact:

```
gg + facet_wrap(~ fac_1 + fac_2)
```

[image]